# How can I make an embeded drop down list in an Extjs editable grid always visible?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is it posible to make a drop down list always visible in a editabel grid ? With the default setup/configuration the drop down only apear when the cell is clicked on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this is possible because of the way the editor is set up. The editor (wether it is a row editor or cell editor) is a re-usable object that is loaded with 1 record at a time. If the editor would be shown for multiple rows at a time you would require multiple editor objects as well.